# synchronized(Object) { } problems

Tags: java, synchronized, concurrency

I have ran into a perfomance problem where 880 threads are doing `synchronized() { method() }`  in the same time and this has lead to a major perfomance problem.

Is it possible that there is some limit of threads waiting at `synchronized()`? Where can I get the limit?

Another question is what is best to put into `synchronized( ? )`. Because I have different classes accessing that variable, so I can not put `synchronized(this)`.

Comment: Can you explain your context better, and such methods.  You might be using the wrong data structure.

Comment: 880 threads?! It's not surprising that you have performance problems. Could you solve your problem with fewer threads and using asynchronous operations instead?

Comment: What is the "major performance problem"? 879 deadlocked threads?

Comment: Context switching. Also each thread has its own stack, so having too many threads can cause out of memory exceptions.

Comment: Mark Byers: Even a rusty old 32-bit OS should be able to cope with 880 threads without problem. Steve Kuo: If each thread use a couple of 4K pages, you are still only talking 1% of a GB.

Comment: The total stack space is limited (it's not using the heap). On a 32-bit Windows machine the maximum simultaneous threads is somewhere around 1000-2000. My point is that there is a limit, and it's in the order of thousands, so 880 is getting close.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to limit anything with synchronized, for advanced concurrency constructs you need to have a look at http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html.

Regarding what you put inside synchronized(**?**), which means on what you lock on, it depends on the locking behavior you want to achieve. If you have a global (for example **public static Object LOCK = new Object();**) which is accessible from all different classes, and you synchronize on that, then all classes will be locking on that one.

Have a look at the [java tutorial on synchronization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html).